# Report Design Suggestion Required

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I am working on *iReport* for the following report design. Look at the format below given :-

[image: Report Design]

After looking into this design, i can conclude the following points.

1. This report basically is based on employees whose work is summarized based on the applications they have worked on, along with their statuses.
2. To me it seems like a Cross tab report.
3. If i am using POJO as a datasource, basically, if i design the DTO, it would be something like a POJO, containing a list of Employees. That Employee POJO itself will be a having a collection of Application types, which in turn will be having a list of statuses.

I am a novice in *JasperReports*. What i am looking forward is, how can we design the datasource in 
order to achieve the report design. Any suggestions are welcome. Sample DTO Design is

package com.renaissance.model;

```
import java.util.List;

public class Employee {
  private long employeeNo ;
  private List<ApplicationType> applicationTypes;

  public Employee(long employeeNo, List<ApplicationType> applicationTypes) {
    this.employeeNo = employeeNo;
    this.applicationTypes = applicationTypes;
  }

  public Employee() {

  }

  public long getEmployeeNo() {
    return employeeNo;
  }

  public void setEmployeeNo(long employeeNo) {
    this.employeeNo = employeeNo;
  }

  public List<ApplicationType> getApplicationTypes() {
    return applicationTypes;
  }

  public void setApplicationTypes(List<ApplicationType> applicationTypes) {
    this.applicationTypes = applicationTypes;
  }
}


package com.renaissance.model;

import java.util.List;

public class ApplicationType {
  private long appTypeId ;
  private String appName ;
  private List<ApplicationStatus> applicationStatuses;

  public List<ApplicationStatus> getApplicationStatuses() {
    return applicationStatuses;
  }

  public void setApplicationStatuses(List<ApplicationStatus> applicationStatuses) {
    this.applicationStatuses = applicationStatuses;
  }

  public long getAppTypeId() {
    return appTypeId;
  }

  public void setAppTypeId(long appTypeId) {
    this.appTypeId = appTypeId;
  }

  public String getAppName() {
    return appName;
  }

  public void setAppName(String appName) {
    this.appName = appName;
  }

  public ApplicationType(long appTypeId, String appName) {
    this.appTypeId = appTypeId;
    this.appName = appName;
  }

  public ApplicationType() {

  }
}

package com.renaissance.model;

public class ApplicationStatus {
  private long appStatusId ;
  private String appStatusNameEn ;

  public ApplicationStatus(long appStatusId, String appStatusNameEn) {
    this.appStatusId = appStatusId;
    this.appStatusNameEn = appStatusNameEn;
  }

  public ApplicationStatus() {

  }

  public long getAppStatusId() {
    return appStatusId;
  }

  public void setAppStatusId(long appStatusId) {
    this.appStatusId = appStatusId;
  }

  public String getAppStatusNameEn() {
    return appStatusNameEn;
  }

  public void setAppStatusNameEn(String appStatusNameEn) {
    this.appStatusNameEn = appStatusNameEn;
  }
}
```

Driver program

```
package com.renaissance.reporting;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import com.renaissance.model.ApplicationStatus;
import com.renaissance.model.ApplicationType;
import com.renaissance.model.Employee;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter;

public class GenerateReport {
  public static final String REPORT_DIRECTORY = "c:\\reporting";
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JRException {
    JRDataSource jrDataSource = prepareDataSource();
    JasperPrint jasperPrint =  generateJasperReportPrint(jrDataSource,REPORT_DIRECTORY+"\\crosstabTest.jasper");
    JRPdfExporter pdfExporter = new JRPdfExporter();
    pdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT,jasperPrint);
    pdfExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,
        REPORT_DIRECTORY + "//" + "test" + ".pdf");
    System.out.println("Exporting report...");
    pdfExporter.exportReport();
    System.out.println("Done!");

  }

  private static JRDataSource prepareDataSource(){
    List<ApplicationStatus> applicationStatuses1 = new ArrayList<ApplicationStatus>();
    List<ApplicationStatus> applicationStatuses2 = new ArrayList<ApplicationStatus>();
    List<ApplicationStatus> applicationStatuses3 = new ArrayList<ApplicationStatus>();
    List<ApplicationType> applicationTypes1 = new ArrayList<ApplicationType>();
    List<ApplicationType> applicationTypes2 = new ArrayList<ApplicationType>();
    List<ApplicationType> applicationTypes3 = new ArrayList<ApplicationType>();



    applicationStatuses1.add(new ApplicationStatus(2,"Approved")) ;
    applicationStatuses1.add(new ApplicationStatus(3,"Rejected")) ;
    applicationStatuses1.add(new ApplicationStatus(4,"NSD Cleared"));

    applicationStatuses2.add(new ApplicationStatus(10,"Approved")) ;
    applicationStatuses2.add(new ApplicationStatus(5,"Rejected")) ;
    applicationStatuses2.add(new ApplicationStatus(6,"NSD Cleared"));



    ApplicationType applicationType1 = new ApplicationType();
    ApplicationType applicationType2 = new ApplicationType();
    ApplicationType applicationType3 = new ApplicationType();
    ApplicationType applicationType4 = new ApplicationType();
    applicationType1.setAppTypeId(1);
    applicationType1.setAppName("Short Term");
    applicationType1.setApplicationStatuses(applicationStatuses1);

    applicationType2.setAppTypeId(2);
    applicationType2.setAppName("Long Term");
    applicationType2.setApplicationStatuses(applicationStatuses2);

    applicationType3.setAppTypeId(3);
    applicationType3.setAppName("Outpass");
    applicationType3.setApplicationStatuses(applicationStatuses1);


    Employee employee1 = new Employee();
    Employee employee2 = new Employee();
    employee1.setEmployeeNo(1);
    employee2.setEmployeeNo(2);
    applicationTypes1.add(applicationType1);
    applicationTypes1.add(applicationType2);
    applicationTypes2.add(applicationType3);
    employee1.setApplicationTypes(applicationTypes1);
    employee2.setApplicationTypes(applicationTypes2);

    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    employees.add(employee1);
    employees.add(employee2);

    return new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(employees);
  }

  private static JasperPrint generateJasperReportPrint(JRDataSource dataSource, String reportPath)
      throws JRException, IOException {
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    try {

      inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(reportPath));
      jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(inputStream, new HashMap(), dataSource);
    }
    catch(IOException e) {

      if (inputStream != null) {
        try {
          inputStream.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e1) {
          e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
      }
    }
    return jasperPrint;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show something what you have already done (template, *Java* code)?

Comment: @AlexK , i just did the sample pojo's and the driver program. it's just a dummy data no service and stuff is implemented. Let me edit the question to add code.

Comment: @AlexK, i don't think so the design is even appropriate to be utilized in the ireport design itself.

Comment: You can use *JRBeanCollectionDataSource* or *JRBeanArrayDataSource* datasource. [JasperReports - Data Source Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#datasources)

Comment: @AlexK i am already doing it. My point is that, is the report snapshot i added, is it kind of cross tab. If it is and if you think my design is correct how i can employ this datasource to create crosstab because it is like iterating from a collection to collection. Obviously cross tab will work on one dataset. If you see Employee has collection of application types and i cant use it in cross tab.

Comment: What is a reason to use collection in *Employee* Bean? And why it is a problem?

Comment: Ok. I see - you need to display statuses.

Comment: @AlexK actually this is a employee based report. It shows what kind of applications an employee worked on. For example if the applications are visa types e.g. Short Term / Tourist, then what were the number of statuses as Approved or Rejected. So seeing this, i don't think my design is compatible to be used as a crosstab.

Comment: Yes, I think the *crosstab* is not the best choice in this case. You can use *Detail* band and *Grouping*. Or you can try to use *Table* element. Don't forget to sort your beans for correct grouping data

Comment: @AlexK, my only confusion is that even if don't use cross tab and we are using grouping and tables. But ideally table can also only work on one collection, where in this regarding we are having collection inside collection. For example application type has application statuses, how we can work around this issue?

Comment: You can iterate on statuses with help of *subreports* or *List* element, for example. You can pass the datasource to *List* component initiated from field that contains *Collection of statuses*

Comment: @AlexK, so by no way we can achieve this similar layout in ireport using any feature?

Comment: You can implement this design with *iReport*

Answer (score 0):

I would use iReport's Crosstab element to aggregate the data presented here and it should work fine for your use case.

As for your data structure, I would try to de-normalize it.

So if you had nested objects, just treat it like a single object and let iReport aggregate data based on the grouping criteria of the crosstab.

It would be similar if you hadnt even been working from a POJO and it was pulling data from a SQL Database. You would have a bag of records with Emp No, Emp Name, Application Type, Status.

From there the crosstab design is relatively easy, go through the wizard (if you are using iReport) specify the Emp No as your Row Group, the Status as your Column Group, specify count of status as your Aggregate Measure, and add Emp Name, and Application Type as Measures with nothing as your calculation. Modify the layout to your spec, and it should work reasonably well.